# My React Native App is displaying a white screen when opening a Webview

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, browser, webview

I created a React Web application that is hosted in IIS on a computer on the client's network.  I use my react native app just to open this React Web application in  a Webview using the "react-native-webview" library.

On my Android 11.0 device I can access the web application normally using the webview. However, I cannot access it on my Android 7.1.2 device with the same webview.  The tests were carried out both on the same network and with the same webview apk.  In the Chrome browser I can normally access the application on the Android 7.1.2 device.  What can I do to make the web application appear normally when using the webview on Android 7.1.2?